# useTransition type error in React(Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

### Bug Report

```
const [index, set] = useState(0);

const transitions = useTransition(slides[index], (item: Slides) => item.id, {
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
    config: config.molasses,
});

console.log(transitions);

useEffect(() => void setInterval(() => set((state) => (state + 1) % 4), 2000), []);

return (
    <Wrapper className={className}>
        {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => (
            <animated.div key={key} class='bg' style={{ ...props, backgroundImage: `url(${item.url}` }} />
        ))}
    </Wrapper>
);
```

results in this:

> Argument of type '{ from: { opacity: number; }; enter: { opacity:
> number; }; leave: { opacity: number; }; config: { readonly tension:
> 280; readonly friction: 120; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'any[]'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and
> 'from' does not exist in type 'any[]'.  TS2345
>
> ```
> 31 | 
> 32 |        const transitions = useTransition(slides[index], (item: Slides) => item.id, {
> 33 |                from: { opacity: 0 },
> ```

**git repo** : https://github.com/LOGANLEEE/resume/tree/useTranstion_issue

### Environment

```
"react-spring": "^9.0.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
```

Comment: useTransition syntax is changed in v9. The documentation is not updated yet on the main site. You can check the new syntax here: https://aleclarson.github.io/react-spring/v9/breaking-changes/#The-useTransition-hook